# reactjs can't read https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js:37752:65

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to follow [this](https://codeutopia.net/blog/2016/01/10/getting-started-with-react-the-easy-way/) tutorial so I copied the following code (from below the sub heading "Step 2: Adding JSX into the mix") directly into a file called index.html which I opened in chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      // Code omitted to keep sample short
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I got this error in the chrome console:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js:37752:65
    at Object.423../isArguments (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js:37761:2)
    at s (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js:2:619)
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js:2:670
    at Object.421.foreach (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js:37637:12)
    at s (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js:2:619)
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js:2:670
    at Object.420../implementation (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js:37618:14)
    at s (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js:2:619)
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js:2:670
```

I'm not sure what to make of this error or how to fix it. Please note that I have not made any changes to the code, I copied it exactly as it was presented on the tutorial. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-localstorage-property-from-window-access-is-denied-for-this-document ?

Comment: Thanks, that worked so if you'd like you can make that an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Glad it helped :) Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your browser is blocking access for external scripts to the `sessionStorage`.

Try following these steps: https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-localstorage-property-from-window-access-is-denied-for-this-document